# Locations of Elements in the DOM

Tags: debugging, d3.js

I'm currently doing some work with D3 and one of these things I'm finding slightly frustrating is the ability to debug stuff in the DOM. My typical browser of choice is Chrome (latestet update to date version) yet when I try to select stuff in the DOM chrome seems to get very confused!

The circle I've selected in the DOM, isn't even contained within the SVG as far as chrome thinks.

[image]

Having just checked IE11 seems to have similar issues, however Firefox seems to handle it (unfortunately I'm not a big fan of Firefox). It this a common feature that developers using D3 have found workarounds for? Or is everyone using Firefox? Or do I need to go log some bugs against various browsers?

Comment: I think this is a new bug. It worked fine on Chrome as well a couple weeks ago. I have less distance between the displayed and the actual position. Maybe 10 or 20 pixels. I can live with it. But it was flawless not long ago.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks Peter, you may want to add this as an answer and I can accept it if no one else suggests anything. I'll also look at logging a bug with Chrome.

Comment: I posted as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a new bug. It worked fine on Chrome as well a couple weeks ago. 
I have less distance between the displayed and the actual position. Maybe 10 or 20 pixels. So I can live with it. But it was flawless not long ago.